# Substitution to solve $y^{\prime} = 1/(f(y)x+g(y)x^n)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This one is really getting to me, to the point I think there's a mistake. Apparently I'm supposed to find a change of variables that will turn $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{f(y)x+g(y)x^n}$$
into a know ODE, presumably a Bernoulli equation. I really don't see how this is possible, given that $f$ and $g$ can be  *anything* . If someone sees a typo or some small error that, if corrected, makes what I'm asked possible, I'd appreciate it being pointed out. Alternatively, if there is no error, how can it be done? In the latter case assume what you will about the regularity of $f$ and $g$, these exercises rarely state it but in most cases it's safe to assume $\mathcal C^1$, locally Lipschitz, etc.

If it helps (and this is what makes me doubt the "typo hypothesis"), it says to apply later to $y^{\prime} = \frac{\cos y}{1 -x\sin y}$, which is indeed of the mentioned type.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy} = f(y)x+g(y)x^n$ may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = f(y)x+g(y)x^n$$

is the Bernoulli differential equation.

Comment: Ah, well I feel silly now. I guess I was too invested in finding $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that $y^{\prime}$ must be non-zero (which clearly is the case), and that this might not determine $y$ in terms of $x$ uniquely, for certain IVPs, right?